# response.sendRedirect replacing + with space in encrypted URL when receiving in app2?

Tags: java, servlets, encryption, urlencode

On a tomcat, I have two webapplications i.e app1 and app2. I send URL from app1 in encrypted form (using below program) to app2 . I send the URL through `response.sendRedirect(encryptedURL)`.Then at app2 I get this encrypted URL. I see there are some extra characters like +,space( ) in this encrypted URL at app2. I want the exact same URL at app2. I am not getting why these extra characters getting inserted?

Here is the URL at app1 after encryption

```
 Rc9mgB+18chPk6nk1+gzpws6dO5/TSkcOYy8rbuVVTmjE9YjLt5w0EMpuhh+QBKzReYO34pAquf9
 kmYOiwl99jo2kDCCkYHMh/+nxEgs1yrLYagsc/0p5KdYeMy1eWeUQB8KqmNlhtYysrHhOYVuunUi
 dTaEKUTSWd8lPg9/wZfHdBoJgaF40aUW3FeRODVL
```

Here is the value of this encrypted URL at app2 when I get it with req.getParameter("encryptedURL");

```
 Rc9mgB 18chPk6nk1 gzpws6dO5/TSkcOYy8rbuVVTmjE9YjLt5w0EMpuhh QBKzReYO34pAquf9  kmYOiwl99jo2kDCCkYHMh/ nxEgs1yrLYagsc/0p5KdYeMy1eWeUQB8KqmNlhtYysrHhOYVuunUi  dTaEKUTSWd8lPg9/wZfHdBoJgaF40aUW3FeRODVL
```

**Here is the program for encryption**

```
 import java.security.Key;
 import javax.crypto.Cipher;
 import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
 import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
 import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

 public class AESEncryptionDecryptionTest {

   private static final String ALGORITHM       = "AES";
   private static final String myEncryptionKey = "ThisIsFoundation";
   private static final String UNICODE_FORMAT  = "UTF8";

   public static String encrypt(String valueToEnc) throws Exception {
 Key key = generateKey();
 Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
 c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);  
 byte[] encValue = c.doFinal(valueToEnc.getBytes());
 String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encValue);
 return encryptedValue;
   }


private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {
byte[] keyAsBytes;
keyAsBytes = myEncryptionKey.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyAsBytes, ALGORITHM);
return key;
}


}
```

**EDIT:-Looks  like very close to it. here is my new code and finding**

This is the parameter I am encrypting at app1

```
 mySession=84088586B45317C3600978DF9F52A699&securityTok=44a2e4dd89ed1aad438d5e3c16ff528&myurl=https://10.205.112.83:8443
```

// encrypted as you suggested at app1 and sending  encryptedParam as request parameter

//now getting the encryptedParam at app2 from request and decrypted  as per your suggestion . As you can see below 
**everything is decrypted fine at app2 except my URL part(i.e `=https://10.205` replaced with ½‡è˜�Àg¸l½.µbO’)**

```
mySession=84088586B45317C3600978DF9F52A699&securityTok=44a2e4dd89ed1aad438d5e3c16ff528&myurl½‡è˜�Àg¸l½.µbO’112.83:8443
```

**Code is**

```
   public static String encrypt(String valueToEnc) throws Exception {
    Key key = generateKey();
    // Key key = buildKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encValue = c.doFinal(valueToEnc.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT));
    String encryptedValue1 = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encValue);
    String encryptedValue = URLEncoder.encode(encryptedValue1);
    return encryptedValue;
  }

  public static String decrypt(String encryptedValue) throws Exception {
    Key key = generateKey();
    // Key key = buildKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    String decordedValueStr = URLDecoder.decode(encryptedValue);
    byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(decordedValueStr);
    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
    // String try1=new BASE64Encoder().encode(decValue);
    String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
    return decryptedValue;
  }
```

Comment: You should not use `valueToEnc.getBytes()`. You should use `valueToEnc.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT)`. You were told this in another answer.

Comment: I have already mentioned in my answer that you should do decode. And why you should not do decode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `encrypt` method instead of:

```
return encryptedValue;
```

use this code:

```
return URLEncoder.encode(encryptedValue);
```

then on receiving side call URLDecoder#decode:

```
String tmpUrl = URLDecoder.decode(encryptedURL);
// call BASE64Decoder on tmpUrl
// call decrypt on return value of BASE64Decoder
```

Comment: @MSach: I didn't suggest removing `BASE64Encoder.encode` method call. You should call `URLEncoder.encode` on the return value of `BASE64Encoder.encode` in your encrypt method. Likewise on receiving side call `URLDecoder.decode` first then `BASE64Decoder.decode` and finally use your decrypt code.

Comment: Hi Anubhava looks  like very close to it. See my new edit after your suggestion. Waiting for it eaglarly from last two days

Comment: Your new code looks good to me, are you still getting some problem with this approach?

Comment: Thanks Anubhav it solved. At decrypt removed URLDecoder.decode(encryptedValue); Looks like it already decoded

Comment: Anubhava one more thing is that coder.encode(encryptedValue) is deprecated . I think i should go for coder.encode(encryptedValue,"UTF8"); Right?

Comment: also it would be really nice if you can provide inputs on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846901/some-questions-about-urlencoder-and-urldecoder as i am really looking some good points on encoding and decoding?

Comment: Yes you're right: `coder.encode(encryptedValue,"UTF8");` is a preferred one. I will look into your other question and provide my input.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use URLEncoding.

- Use [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) to encode the url in app1.
- Use [URLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) to decode the url in app2.

When server receives the redirected request, anyway it will do URL decode. So you do not have to do it. Just URLEncode in the app1 should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi ramesh if you lok at encrypt method i am doing encoding using BASE64Encoder not •URLEncoder. Simliarly doing decoding using BASE64Decoder(). Are using saying i shud use urlencoder and decoder instead of BASE64Encoder and BASE64Decoder?

Comment: @MSach:  Yes, that is what he is saying.

Comment: @MSach Yes should be doing URLEncoding and URLDecoding

Comment: Hi ramesh. tried that, but same issue. Please look at edited part.With urlencoder, i  encrypted the url at app1 and then decrypted at app1 itself, then also give it gives error

Comment: Did you try doing only URLEncode. Do not do URLDecode on the other side.

Comment: Hi ramesh, it would be really nice if you can provide inputs on stackoverflow.com/questions/10846901/… as i am bit confused about  encoding and decoding and when it requires?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846901/some-questions-about-urlencoder-and-urldecoder