# Some questions about URLEncoder and URLDecoder?

Tags: java, encoding, urlencode

I have gone thru javadocs of URLEncoder and URLDecoder. Then got more inquisitive. Consider the server as tomcat.In any webapplication whenever we submit
the form , server converts the forms fields into urlencoded fields and when we do request.getParamter("fieldName"). Server again decode it with URLDecoder.
    **Is that correct? Does server do it or browser?** Simlary when we type any url in address bar  same stuff happens? **If server or browser does that
    when we require to encode or decode the request paramter explicitly with the help of URLEncoder and URLDecoder?** Though these are basic questions but could not find these anwers clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In any webapplication whenever we submit the form , server converts the forms fields into urlencoded fields and when we do request.getParamter("fieldName").

No. The browser does that.

> Server again decode it with URLDecoder. Is that correct?

Yes.

> Does server do it or browser?

The browser.

> If server or browser does that when we require to encode or decode the request parameter
>   explicitly with the help of URLEncoder and URLDecoder?'

I don't know what that means but it's still the browser. You only need to encode the request parameters if you are sending the request from application code. You don't need to decode them at all if you're running in a servlet container: it will do that for you.

Comment: As you answered that we type the url in browser, browsers does the encoding by default. In my code i had seen when i did response.redirect from my servlet, it did not encode the request parameters. But if browsers do the encoding by default should not response.redirect also do encoding as in case of redirect request is treated as it is fired from browser?

Comment: Looks like response.redirect does not encode the request param as we there is seperate  method i.e response.encodeRedirectURL in response

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that browser does encode a URL before passing it off to the web server but there may not be a browser involvement all the time.

e.g. your server app might be making a REST based call and passing some data in a simple GET request. And then if you don't encode it on your server it may become garbled when receiver decodes it.

Therefore it is highly recommended to always encode the URL before sending it off in your server code.

Comment: Hi anubhava Looks like from the answers that we type the url in browser, browsers does the encoding by default. In my code i had seen when i did response.redirect from my servlet, it did not encode the request parameters. But if browsers do the encoding by default should not response.redirect also do encoding as in case of redirect request is treated as it is fired from browser?

Comment: As you've commented about `response.encodeRedirectURL()` that it is provided for the purpose of encoding the specified URL for use in the sendRedirect method OR if encoding is not needed, returning the URL unchanged.

Comment: One more thing anubhava, at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html , a point says All other characters are unsafe and are first converted into one or more bytes using some encoding scheme, why all other characters are considered unsafe. Is it because hackers can do some manipulations with these characters like they can embed some arbitrary stuff in place od space character. Right?

Comment: @MSach: I don't think that has anything to do with hacking. There is a [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/) out there and it defines a set of allowed characters in URIs. Other than those *safe* character sets rest of them need to be encoded and that is what Java doc is calling `all other characters are considered unsafe`