# javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException : Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher

Tags: java, encryption

I'm getting a decrypting error in java class:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException : 
    Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher.
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

UPDATE:

I forgot to mention it is working once and when the second time im trying to execute it again its throwing the above mentioned error.

```
package com.tb.module.service;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import sun.misc.*;

/**
 * This class is used for encrypt and decrypt the  password field.
 *
 */
public class PswdEnc {

    private static final String ALGO = "AES";
    private static final byte[] keyValue = new byte[] { 'T', 'h', 'e', 'B', 'e', 's', 't','S', 'e', 'c', 'r','e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y' };

    public static String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
        String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
        return encryptedValue;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey(); 
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedData);
        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
        String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
        return decryptedValue;
    }


    private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGO);
        return key;
    }

}
```

Comment: Whatever you're decrypting is the wrong size. It needs to be a multiple of the block size (16) or else it can't be decrypted. How are you getting your decrypted data?

Comment: actually I'm encrypting password before saving it into sql db. then while retrieving I'm trying to decrypt it.

Comment: Are you sure the data you're saving and the data you're reading out is the same length?

Comment: Get the length of the array when you write it to the database, then get it again when you read it out.

Answer (score 93):

The algorithm you are using, "AES", is a shorthand for "AES/ECB/NoPadding". What this means is that you are using the [AES algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) with 128-bit key size and [block size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher), with the [ECB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29) [mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) and [no padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29).

In other words: you are only able to encrypt data in blocks of 128 bits or 16 bytes. That's why you are getting that `IllegalBlockSizeException` exception.

If you want to encrypt data in sizes that are not multiple of 16 bytes, you are either going to have to use some kind of padding, or a cipher-stream. For instance, you could use [CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29) (a mode of operation that effectively transforms a block cipher into a [stream cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher)) by specifying "AES/CBC/NoPadding" as the algorithm, or PKCS5 padding by specifying "AES/ECB/PKCS5", which will automatically add some bytes at the end of your data in a very specific format to make the size of the ciphertext multiple of 16 bytes, and in a way that the decryption algorithm will understand that it has to ignore some data.

In any case, I strongly suggest that you stop right now what you are doing and go study some very introductory material on cryptography. For instance, check [Crypto I on Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/course/crypto). You should understand very well the implications of choosing one mode or another, what are their strengths and, most importantly, their weaknesses. Without this knowledge, it is very easy to build systems which are very easy to break.

---

Update: based on your comments on the question, **don't ever encrypt passwords when storing them at a database**!!!!! You should never, ever do this. You must **HASH** the passwords, properly salted, which is completely different from encrypting. Really, please, don't do what you are trying to do... By encrypting the passwords, they can be decrypted. What this means is that you, as the database manager and who knows the secret key, you will be able to read every password stored in your database. Either you knew this and are doing something very, very bad, or you didn't know this, and should get shocked and stop it.

Comment: I was not aware of the fact that I should not encrypt the password and store it in the database. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @baburao113 then you should really accept the answer

Comment: +1 for recommending hashing over encrypting

Comment: So, awesome mentioning that a hash is better, although more nicely would have been better, but how about giving a clue on what that is and how to accomplish it. That would be even awesomer.

Comment: downvote for drama and condescension. Passwords that must be transmitted as plain text cant be stored as hashes

Answer (score 5):

A few comments:

`import sun.misc.*;` Don't do this.  It is non-standard and not guaranteed to be the same between implementations.  There are other libraries with Base64 conversion available.

`byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());`  You are relying on the default character encoding here.  Always specify what character encoding you are using: `byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes("UTF-8"));`  Defaults might be different in different places.

As @thegrinner pointed out, you need to explicitly check the length of your byte arrays.  If there is a discrepancy, then compare them byte by byte to see where the difference is creeping in.

Comment: *There are other libraries with Base64 conversion available* > Since Java 6, try `DatatypeConverter`.

Answer (score -1):

Well that is Because of

you are only able to encrypt data in blocks of 128 bits or 16 bytes. That's why you are getting that IllegalBlockSizeException exception.
and the one way is to encrypt that data Directly into the String.

look this. Try and u will be able to resolve this

```
public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception {

    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    String decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedData).toString().trim();
    System.out.println("This is Data to be Decrypted" + decordedValue);
    return decordedValue;
}
```

hope that will help.

Comment: sorry, but that code snippet provided does not do decryption. It only decodes the input using Base64. decoding would done using new String(c.doFinal(decodedValue))