# I have encrypted AES Key with AES Key,Stored the Key as String in DataBase, when i try to decrypt the Key i get :

Tags: java, database, encryption, cryptography

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: 
    Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
```

Please check the important Part of code:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");

KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
SecretKey secKey = (SecretKey) keyGen.generateKey();
SecretKey secKey1 = (SecretKey) keyGen1.generateKey();

byte[] stringKey=secKey.getEncoded();

cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secKey1);
byte[] DykeyBytes = cipher.doFinal(stringKey);

StringBuffer sbselect2=new StringBuffer();
sbselect2.append("SELECT keylock FROM ");
sbselect2.append(UserConstants.USER_DETAILS_TABLE_NAME1);
sbselect2.append(" where Username='" + un + "'");
ps2=conn.prepareStatement(sbselect2.toString());
ResultSet rs1 =ps2.executeQuery();
rs1.next();
String Enkey = rs1.getString("keylock");

System.out.println("Encrypted+Encoded key from current user "+Enkey);
rs1.close();

//decrypting the DB stored Key
Cipher cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
cipher2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, singlekey );
byte[] dynamicKey = Enkey.getBytes("UTF8");
// below is where the error points  to at user.dao.UserDao.isRegisteredUser(UserDao.java:313)
byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher2.doFinal(dynamicKey);

Object DeKey = new String(decryptedBytes);//under check
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(decryptedBytes, "AES");
```

Comment: Let me add another point: i found the input length of the String is 48 and when is retrieve it back from database it is 58

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17247573/1811853

Comment: Please don't revert edits that improve the readability and formatting of your question.

Comment: i am sorry it was not intentional.

Comment: Is there a way around for this problem

Comment: Hi had managed to solve one problem for the length of the String retrieved from database: i had changed from UTF8 to unicode for the key column, CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NULL ;  But now i got an issue javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded

Comment: How did you generate the key and how did you put it into the database?

Comment: we can see this part of code where i had converted byte to a string and stored it in the data base                      byte[] stringKey=secKey.getEncoded();

cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secKey1);
byte[] DykeyBytes = cipher.doFinal(stringKey);

Comment: then is recover the String to byte and pass it through SecretKeySpec                                                               Before encryption Key: javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@1735b
After encryption Key : ???????????????????
After decryption Key: javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@19cb8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys i am very happy today  i tried several types of logic and at last i found the answer an answer, and i believe i am the first person to get it. Hip Hip hurray. Its my hardwork paid off started working on it from 10 AM till 6 PM.

Here is the Process

Secret Key generated ---Base64Enocder---Encrypted with similar secretkey--Base64Encoded--     converted to String--stored in database---retrieved String---Base64Decoder---Decryption--  Base64Decoder--SecretKeySpec--walla her is the key

OutPut:
    Before encryption Key: javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@178e7  .
    base64: UKcvVLp9L51xxHHyLIRrgQ==  .
    base64double: wu8CBPMELHgp6WAGGFgHGWjPXn4MRibeZ9IKGRTpjJE= .
    After encrypting base64 : wu8CBPMELHgp6WAGGFgHGWjPXn4MRibeZ9IKGRTpjJE=  .
    After decryption base64double : [B@1cfe433  .
    After decryption base64 : [B@18f11d3  .
    After base64decoder and keyspec : javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@178e7   .

Comment: Forgot to say change the Key column to unicode instead of UTF8

Comment: Proof of final resuts                                              iv[] output ---- [B@a6d290
Before encryption Key: javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@17b62
encrypted password for encrypted bytes+ ????????
encrypted password for encrypted bytes length 8



iv bytes data from db---[B@1a35b19
decoded and decrypted key ++javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@17b62
encrypted password for encrypted bytes+ ????????
encrypted password for encrypted bytes length 8