# javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException during decode

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, keystore, android-keystore

After trying to store the password in Android KeyStore I get an `javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException`. Here is my code:

```
    public static String decode(String encodedString, Cipher cipher) {
    try {
        byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.NO_WRAP); // bytes.length= 44, as I know it should be multiple of 16, am I right ? How to make it right ?
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(bytes)); // getting the error here
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Used algorithm:

```
    private static final String TRANSFORMATION = "RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding";
```

I get the following error:

```
    javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException
at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:513)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1741)
at com.mayzusfs.android.moneypolo.app.utils.CryptoUtils.decode(CryptoUtils.java:82) // the line of the above method
at com.mayzusfs.android.moneypolo.app.FingerprintHandler.onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintHandler.java:51)
at android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager$MyHandler.sendAuthenticatedSucceeded(FingerprintManager.java:975)
at android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager$MyHandler.handleMessage(FingerprintManager.java:896)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Invalid input length
at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:697)
at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.doFinal(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:224)
at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:506)
```

Also, I have found an interesting thing, after encryption the byte[] length is 256, but after the decode it becomes 44:

```
public static String encode(String inputString) {
    try {
        inputString = Encryptor.toMd5Hash(inputString);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        if (prepare() && initCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE)) {
            byte[] bytes = sCipher.doFinal(inputString.getBytes()); // length is 256
            return Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        }
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am new in encryption, so please sorry if the question is a bit dully. I also have tryed to google it and faced the following solutions but they did not help me ( maybe I have done something wrong ):
[javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException : Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234359/javax-crypto-illegalblocksizeexception-input-length-must-be-multiple-of-16-whe)

[javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/168444/javax-crypto-IllegalBlockSizeException)

Comment: Obviously, somehow the data has been corrupted between the time you encrypted it and the time it got to your decryption code. As to how that corruption occurred, your question does not include any information that would help diagnose that.

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying that you don't want wrapping during *decoding* so if lines are wrapped then you may get a different result. Normally however the lines are wrapped after 76 characters, which produce 57, not 44 bytes of data.

So that means that - for some reason - the base 64 decoder stopped *before* the end of the string was reached or that the string wasn't the right size in the first place. This could e.g. be the case if you try and read a file, and expect the `read` methods to always return the full size of the file.

Print out the base 64 string after encoding and before decoding to be sure. The output size of 256 bytes is expected, as it is equal to the key size in bytes (which means you used a 2048 bit RSA key).