# Code fails for decrypting without salt or iv in Java

Tags: java, security, encryption, aes, password-encryption

I have a ciphertext and a 256-bit key to decrypt it, using AES. There is no salt or iv. I am using Java. I have implemented many of the solutions online, but they all use salts and input vectors. The following builds fine, but fails at runtime: "Salt not found." What salt?

```
    public class AESFileDecryption {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String password = "80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01";

    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray());
    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(keySpec);
    SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

    // file decryption
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance();
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,secret);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("encryptedfile.des");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("plainfile_decrypted.txt");
    byte[] in = new byte[64];
    int read;
    while ((read = fis.read(in)) != -1) {
        byte[] output = cipher.update(in, 0, read);
        if (output != null)
            fos.write(output);
    }

    byte[] output = cipher.doFinal();
    if (output != null)
        fos.write(output);
    fis.close();
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    System.out.println("File Decrypted");
}
```

}

Comment: StackOverflow is for specific questions related to programming. You have a specification, which I assume is homework or an assignment. You need to read the spec, do some research and/or learning, and start writing a solution. StackOverflow will not write your code for you. If you encounter problems while coding your solution, post additional questions.

Comment: If you phrased this as "How does decryption work without a salt or IV?" instead of "I need code that does ..." then it would probably be a better question.

Comment: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 requires a salt.  I presume Schneier is giving you the key directly, so it means you should not be using PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1.  See comment in my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decrypt the ciphertext in exercise 3.8 by using the simple ECB mode of AES, which does not use an IV. Since you have the key, there is no need for salt (there is no key derivation). Use AES 256 ECB mode in Java, and pass the key as shown. These openssl commands at the command line show that this will work:

You have to convert the hex shown in the book to a string of bytes, for example:

```
echo '539B333B39706D149028CFE1D9D4A407' | xxd -r -p
```

You have to use the key as a string of 32 bytes, for example, the openssl command line converts hex to bytes for you with the -K argument:

```
-K 80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

And you can convert the resulting binary plaintext back to a hex string for viewing, as in

```
xxd -p
```

For example:

```
echo '539B333B39706D149028CFE1D9D4A407' | xxd -r -p | openssl enc -aes-256-ecb -nopad  -d -K 8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 | xxd -p
```

The result is:

```
80706050403020100807060504030201
```

If you let the Java class strip the padding, the result will be 15 bytes of plaintext as:

```
807060504030201008070605040302
```

This should be enough for you to jump in with the Java classes and reproduce the same result. I just wanted to show you that this will work with AES 256 ECB, without any IV or salt involved.

Comment: Thank you very much. While I was editing my question in response to previous criticism, you answered with this very helpfully. (For anyone wondering why the answer seems a bit off topic, the fault is mine).

Answer (score 0):

IVs are normally used with encryption modes such as CBC.  I'm assuming Schneier is using ECB here, which doesn't involve an IV.  ECB mode is not normally used in the real world because it lacks security.  I would advise you to have a look at the WIkipedia [modes of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) article.  Salts are even more off.

If you agree that this is the problem you are dealing with, then you might want to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22034269/encryption-decryption-using-aes-ecb-nopadding) for java code to encrypt in ECB mode.

Comment: Thanks, I will pursue those. I am actually getting a lot out of Schneier's book. I just need to understand security really thoroughly, so I'm delving into code territory as a relative newbie, and was having trouble with that exercise.

Comment: No worries. Actually, although I have not seen Schneier's book, I do know crypto pretty well, and I am quite sure your problem is the "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1".  PBKDF2 is for turning a password into a key, whereas I am guessing that Schneier gives you the key directly (not a password).  See the link I cited ("here" above) for how to set the key properly.  And the other thing in the link is using ECB mode rather than CBC, which is what you should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Both the answers here are correct about using ECB and therefore not requiring an IV (or padding).  Here's an updated Java answer for question 3.8:

```
String hexCipherText = "539b333b39706d149028cfe1d9d4a407";
String hexSecretKey =  "80000000000000000000000000000000" +
                       "00000000000000000000000000000001";

byte[] secretKey = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary (hexSecretKey);
byte[] cipherText = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary (hexCipherText);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey,"AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);

byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
String hexPlainText = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(plainText);
```

If you get the error `java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters` and you're using the Oracle JDK then you may also need to download the [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html).