# Decrypting string generates IllegalBlockSizeException

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I have problems when processing the decrypt method. Encryption is producing a correct output but when I decrypt the exact same encrypted string, (that should be back into plaintext string), it does not work.

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Samp {

    private static String IV = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    private static final String UNICODE_FORMAT = "UTF8";

    private String padd(String plaintext) {
        while (plaintext.length() % 16 != 0) {
            plaintext += "\0";
        }
        return plaintext;
    }

    public String encryptString(String plaintext, String encryptionKey) {
        try {
            byte[] cipher = encrypt(padd(plaintext), encryptionKey);
            return new String(cipher, UNICODE_FORMAT);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public String decryptString(String encString, String encryptionKey) {
        try {
            System.out.println("**** decryptString ****");
            System.out.println("enc = " + encString);
            System.out.println("key = " + encryptionKey);

            String decrypted = decrypt(encString.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT), encryptionKey);
            return decrypted;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static byte[] encrypt(String plainText, String encryptionKey) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding", "SunJCE");
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT)));
        return cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT));
    }

    private static String decrypt(byte[] cipherText, String encryptionKey) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding", "SunJCE");
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT)));
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(cipherText), UNICODE_FORMAT);
    }
    // implement methods here
    // using AES simple encryption

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String plaintext = "Hello World!";
        String key = "asdfqaqwsaerdqsw";

        Samp s = new Samp();
        String enc = s.encryptString(plaintext, key);
        System.out.println("encrypted string = " + enc);
        String dec = s.decryptString(enc, key);
        System.out.println("decrypted string = " + dec);
    }
}
```

I've already seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836139/getting-javax-crypto-illegalblocksizeexception-input-length-must-be-multiple-of), which has the same problem as mine. I followed the suggestions(change getBytes() -> getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT)) but it is still the same. I still get an exception (javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length not multiple of 16 bytes)

Comment: if you are using a `NoPadding` algorithm why are you padding to 16 bytes in `padd`

Comment: it does not work well if i don't padd, so I decided to padd the plaintext and it worked

Comment: Note that padding with zero characters is ambiguous: on deciphering there's no way to tell whether trailing zeroes are part of the original string or part of padding.

Comment: Yes i also noticed that. What would you suggest @JeffreyHantin

Comment: [PKCS#7 padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7) is unambiguous: padding consists of *n* trailing bytes all of value *n*.

Comment: Also, you can tell the JCE to apply PKCS#7 padding for you; rather than specifying `NoPadding`, specify `PKCS5Padding` (an older version of the specification that only defines padding for 8-byte block ciphers, but JCE requires the older name).

Comment: I like that algorithm, it's clean and makes sense.

Comment: should I replace the "AES/CBC/NoPadding" with "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" for both encrypt and decrypt? sorry I am new to cryptography

Comment: @krato Precisely, then you can leave off the padding code entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an encoding that is 1 to 1 mapping between characters and bytes, such as "ISO-8859-1". So change your code to

```
private static final String UNICODE_FORMAT = "ISO-8859-1";
```

solves the problem.

Comment: nice!! It solved the problem but how? Can you explain?

Comment: Using plain text to represent the encrypted data is plain wrong. Encrypted data can and will contain all byte values from 0 to 255, which are not all printable characters. You must use HEX or Base64 encoding instead of simply converting the byte array into a string.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin Thank you for pointing it out. OP does it anyways, and I have no intention to change the way he handles the encrypted data. For study or practice purpose, I think it's alright.

Comment: @krato You need 1-to-1 mapping encoding so `encString.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT)` gives you the correct cipher

Answer (score 3):

```
  public String encryptString(String plaintext, String encryptionKey)
```

The problem is right here. String is not a container for binary data. This method should return a byte[]. Similarly the decrypt() method should take a byte[] as the ciphertext parameter, not a String.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Or *don't* encode the bytes, and completely eliminate the occasion of the problem, and completely prevent its recurrence by uninformed tinkering later on, by designing the method signatures correctly in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

here is my code which works

```
public static String encrypt(String data) throws Exception {

        SecretKeySpec key = generateKey();
        final Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/EAX/NoPadding", "BC");

        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);

        byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF8"));       

        String encryptedValue = Hex.toHexString(encVal);
        return encryptedValue;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception {

        Key key = generateKey();
        final Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/EAX/NoPadding", "BC");

        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
        byte[] ba = Hex.decode(encryptedData);

        byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(ba);  

        return new String (encVal);

    }
```