# Getting error javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input should be multiple of 8, when decrypting passwords with Java

Tags: java, encryption, javax

Here I add passwords and sites connected to them to my database, I think this works fine. I can see the crypted password in database when I examine it:

```
public static void lisaa(PreparedStatement statement, ResultSet resultSet, 
    Connection connection, Scanner lukija, Kryptaaja kc)throws SQLException, 
    Exception {
    System.out.println("Sivu salasanalle: ");
    String sivu = lukija.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Salasana: ");
    String ss = lukija.nextLine();
    String[] sanabytes = new String[] {ss};


    statement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO PASSWORDS (sivu, 
    salasana) VALUES(?, ?)");
    statement.setString(1, sivu);
    statement.setString(2, kc.kryptaa(sanabytes));
   statement.executeUpdate();
}
```

My method that retrieves crypted passwords from the database and tries to print them:

```
public static void tulosta(PreparedStatement statement, ResultSet resultSet, 
    Connection connection, Kryptaaja kc)throws SQLException, Exception {
    statement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from PASSWORDS");
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
    boolean onko = false;
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        onko = true;
      String sivu = resultSet.getString("sivu");
      String ss = resultSet.getString("salasana");

     String[] sanabytes = new String[]{ss};
     String dekryptattu = kc.tulkkaa(sanabytes);
     System.out.println(sivu + ": " + dekryptattu );
   }
   if (!onko) {
    System.out.println("ei kappaleita!");
  }
```

}

My class that Cryptes and Decryptes the password. Ignore the comments, this is just for testing, they are there to clarify me what code does(not mine):

```
public Kryptaaja(){

}
```

Crypting the password, this one works I think:

```
 public String kryptaa (String[] args) throws Exception {
    //
    // Check args and get plaintext
    if (args.length !=1) {
        System.err.println("Usage: java PrivateExample text");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    byte[] plainText = args[0].getBytes("UTF8");
    //
    // Get a DES private key
    KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");

    // If you do not initialize the KeyGenerator, each provider supply a default initialization.
    keyGen.init(56);
    Key key = keyGen.generateKey();
    //
    // Creates the DES Cipher object (specifying the algorithm, mode, and padding).
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    // Print the provider information       
    //
    // Initializes the Cipher object.
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    // Encrypt the plaintext using the public key
    byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
    String kryptattu = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText);
    String erikryptattu = ( new String(cipherText, "UTF8") );
    return kryptattu;
}
```

Method to decrypt the password, I think the problem my lie in here:

```
 public String tulkkaa (String[] args) throws Exception {
    //
    // Check args and get plaintext
    if (args.length !=1) {
        System.err.println("Usage: java PrivateExample text");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    byte[] krypted = args[0].getBytes("UTF8");
    //
    // Get a DES private key
    KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");

    // If you do not initialize the KeyGenerator, each provider supply a default initialization.
    keyGen.init(56);
    Key key = keyGen.generateKey();
    //
    // Creates the DES Cipher object (specifying the algorithm, mode, and padding).
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    // Initializes the Cipher object.
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    // Decrypt the ciphertext using the same key
    byte[] newPlainText = cipher.doFinal(krypted);
```

Here I encode the bytes -> String:

```
    String sana = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(newPlainText);
    String eri =( new String(newPlainText, "UTF8") );
    return sana;
}
```

}

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836139/getting-javax-crypto-illegalblocksizeexception-input-length-must-be-multiple-of?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

As a preliminary, it's a bad idea to encrypt passwords (rather than comparing a proper password hash, *not* a plain crypto hash) unless you really know what you're doing. It's a terrible idea to encrypt passwords with DES, which has been broken for 20 years, and ECB, which with a small blocksize makes it possible to break many values without even decrypting. However, security is the topic of security.SX not stackoverflow, so I'll assume you don't want to actually have security.

Your big problem is that you generate two different keys: you encrypt with one key and then try to decrypt with a different key. This is completely broken; the basis of conventional (formally, 'symmetric') cryptography since the beginning of history is that encryption and decryption **use the same key**. Even modern 'asymmetric' aka public-key cryptography uses keys in matched pairs: given a keypair P1 you can encrypt with the public part of P1 and decrypt with the private part of P1, but not some different keypair P2 or Px.

Since you want to store encrypted data to be decrypted at a later time, you need to store the key that will be used to decrypt, in a fashion that prevents it being used by an unauthorized party. This is (part of) what is called Key Management, and is the actually hard part of doing security, much harder than simply encrypting and decrypting. You give so little information about what you want to do and in what environment that I can't give any concrete recommendation.

If you change to a better mode than ECB you also need to store an Initialization Vector (IV) (or equivalent) for each encrypted value, but this is easier because IVs don't need to be secret.

---

Your code `String erikryptattu = ( new String(cipherText, "UTF8") );` *would* be another error except that this is dead code; you never use this value.

For electronic and computer cryptography (i.e. since about 1950), ciphertext values (and also hashes, MACs, and signatures) is arbitrary essentially random bits; it is not characters and trying to treat it as characters, as Java `String` does, will usually mangle it, and particularly will change ciphertext so that it cannot be decrypted (even with the correct key, and IV). So don't do that. Using base64, as your live code does, is one good way to handle arbitrary bits.

But you need to do it completely. Your decrypt routine `tulkkaa` needs to **base64-decode the ciphertext** before decrypting it.