# Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher in GSTR7

Tags: java, encryption

How can I resolve this error when I run the following code?

```java
String decrypted_appkey = "41+sD/gm9DWQeZbJm98qb3ss9Eu96XkClU5a4hyfaAw=";
String receivedSEK = "0x5D112907B134B9CE30E30745F48A536845521B04F6B912552AAA65B563F01CC0";
decryptedSek = NICEncrypt.decrypt(receivedSEK, decodeBase64StringTOByte(decrypted_appkey));

public static String decrypt(String plainText, byte[] secret)
     throws InvalidKeyException, IOException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
     BadPaddingException, Exception {
     SecretKeySpec sk = new SecretKeySpec(secret, AES_ALGORITHM);
     DECRYPT_CIPHER.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sk);
     byte[] bytes = DECRYPT_CIPHER.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(plainText));
     return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
}
private static byte[] decodeBase64StringTOByte(String stringData) throws Exception {
     return java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(stringData.getBytes(CHARACTER_ENCODING));
}
```

Output:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher  at
com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.prepareInputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1005) at 
com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:848) at 
com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446) at 
javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2164)
```

Comment: Can you please post your exception also

Comment: Yes. It's "javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher"

Comment: Possible duplicate of:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836139/getting-javax-crypto-illegalblocksizeexception-input-length-must-be-multiple-of

Comment: @SJN Currently the code is not compilable by anybody (`NICEncrypt` ???) and therefore off topic. But please note that a `BadPaddingException` may happen on *any* error with the key, ciphertext or even IV (apart from issues with the size). So pointing to another answer that has the same exception without justification is not a good idea.

Comment: `Cipher` carries state, and should never be a `static` value. Decryption handles ciphertext. Your method is fully stringified, which is a known anti-pattern. The base64 decoding should be a one liner and doesn't need character encoding, it can handle strings just as well. Exceptions are not correctly handled. You should unwrap rather than decrypt. That's a very badly programmed piece of code, in other words.

Answer (score 1):

Commonly so called wrapped keys are not padded at all. What you have received may well be an encrypted 256 bit (AES) key. Usually you'd use `"AES/ECB/NoPadding"` for that, but without protocol specification that's just an informed guess. Note that - for the standard provider - the `"AES"` string defaults to `"AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"` and will try to unpad.

Furthermore, your wrapped key is clearly not in base 64, it is in hexadecimals. You first need to decode the hexadecimals, and exclude the `"0x"` in front of the wrapped key.

Comment: Come to think of it, it could also be CBC/CTR/CFB/OFB/whatever encrypted with a prefixed IV, but *that* would not be common practice. I'll not go into SIV mode, too new, too advanced.

Answer (score 0):

`receivedSEK` is not in Base64, but seemingly some "hex" string.

```
String receivedSEK = "0x5D112907B134B9CE30E30745F48A536845521B04F6B912552AAA65B563F01CC0";
int n = (receivedSEK.length() - 2) / 2;
byte[] bytes = new byte[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    bytes[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(receivedSEK.substring(2 + 2*i, 4 + 2*i), 16);
}
decryptedSek = NICEncrypt.decrypt(bytes, decodeBase64StringTOByte(decrypted_appkey));

public static String decrypt(byte[] bytes, byte[] secret)
     throws InvalidKeyException, IOException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
     BadPaddingException, Exception {
     SecretKeySpec sk = new SecretKeySpec(secret, AES_ALGORITHM);
     DECRYPT_CIPHER.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sk);
     byte[] bytes = DECRYPT_CIPHER.doFinal(bytes);
     return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
}

private static byte[] decodeBase64StringTOByte(String stringData) throws Exception {
     return Base64.getDecoder().decode(stringData);
}
```

Also Base64 decoding is simpler.

Comment: Good try, but it will still generate the error. I checked the output.

Comment: (I had parseInt ..., 15 i.o. 16). Though much hope for this kind of coding attempts I do not have.

Comment: That's not the problem, **if** the input, key and algorithm are correct then the input was never padded, see my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. We tried with shared code changes  however no joy! Now we are getting error as "javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption."